# How to make a specific Tree Node to appear as a folder in a Tree View

Tags: c#, winforms

How to make a specific Tree Node to appear as a folder in a Tree View?
I am creating a dynamic Tree View using a table in my database and based on one column i.e., NodeType having value (1 or 2), I want it to either appear as folder or as a normal tree node.

Pseudo code will be more beneficial.

[image: desired result]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "appearing as a folder". The in-built TreeView control has a text-based GUI (which, on the hand, is not easy to be modify). Do you want to create a custom TreeView Control showing what exactly? A picture of a folder when you want?

Comment: I want an icon which will make a node look like folder....

Comment: Clear. VahidND has been quicker than me (+1 for him). If you get distracted 5 mins in a C#-tagged answer, you lose your opportunity :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put your folder image in an ImageList control and set the ImageList property of the TreeView control to this imagelist and when creating nodes set ImageIndex of that node to the desired index.

```
    TreeNode tn = new TreeNode();
    if (imageShouldBeFolderImage)
        tn.ImageIndex = 0;

    // If you want to show another image for other cases, 
    // If you want no image ignore this else part
    else            
        tn.ImageIndex = 1;
```

**Update:**

If selecting a node changes it's image to another undesirable image it's caused by the TreeView's SelectedImageIndex property, I suggest adding an empty image to the imagelist and set the nodes SelectedImageIndex.

```
TreeNode tn = new TreeNode();
if (imageShouldBeFolderImage)
{
    tn.ImageIndex = 0;
    tn.SelectedImageIndex = 0;
}
else
{            
    tn.ImageIndex = 1;//the index of the empty image
    tn.SelectedImageIndex = 1;
}
```

Comment: He wants either image or nothing. That is: ImageList consisting in just one image and making tn.ImageIndex = 0 (if image/folder should be displayed) or tn.ImageIndex = 1 (or any other index, when no image should be displayed).

Comment: @varocarbas Exactly! You got my objective. So the above answer doesn't work for me. Rather even I am unable to apply an image to a normal node by hard coding node.ImageIndex = 1;

Comment: @PrakashVishwakarma No, this code works. Just update it as suggested: add an ImageList consisting just in one image (your folder image), link it to the treeview (treeView1.ImageList = imageList1;) and use this code:  tn.ImageIndex = 0; (shows the image) or  tn.ImageIndex = 1; (or to any other index; does not show anything because there is no image with index 1)

Comment: @varocarbas I edited the answer to reflect your clarification.

Comment: All the nodes come up with an folder icon in it. Even if I didn't used node.ImageIndex property. Still it displays folder @varocarbas is concerned for the same thing.

Comment: @PrakashVishwakarma set a loop at the Form_Load iterating throug all the nodes and setting their .ImageIndex  property to 1.

Comment: Good. Someone distracted me 5mins when I was to write my answer and you were quicker :)

Comment: My code :

if(NodeType == 1)
 node.ImageIndex = 0;
else
 node.ImageIndex = 1;


Works but when i click on my normal node, its icon toggles to folder icon i.e., similar to ImageIndex = 0

Comment: @VahidND 'on click event' normal node toggles to folder icon. Could you tell me how can I stop my normal node from toggling to folder icon ?

Comment: @PrakashVishwakarma The problem is caused by SelectedImageIndex property of the TreeView, I'll edit my answer to provide a work around.

Comment: @VahidND I appreciate your valuable efforts. It worked and solved my purpose.